# vSphere API and Additional EULA's

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I've gone through a lot of the APIs and searched to no avail. Is there a way to set or add an additional EULA to a VM? Currently I am trying the Ruby client `RbVmomi` talking to an ESXi 4.0 server. I am able to set other configuration options such as annotations but cannot seem to get the EULA config to stick.

```
vm.ReconfigVM_Task( :spec => VIM.VirtualMachineConfigSpec( :annotation => 'test', :vAppConfig => VIM.VmConfigSpec( :eula => ['test2']))).wait_for_completion
```

Has anyone had any luck with setting EULAs on VMs through the vSphere API?

Answer (score 1):

The EULA is typically contained in the OVF section of the VM. (vm.config.vAppConfig)

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vim.vApp.VmConfigInfo.html

Comment: Isn't that exactly what the sample code does? Setting this value either during import or after import doesn't seem to 'stick'.

Comment: Yup. You have to import it as an OVF, afaik. The EULA will be contained in the product section of the OVF. I believe the VM must be off to make the change, and the vApp option in the GUI must be turned on.